# How do I use my local terminal configurations while working on a remote server through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a very specific terminal setup. It is perfect (for me). The colors are great, the highlighting is great, the key bindings and shortcuts are superb. This is great when working on my local machine, but when I open up an ssh connection to a server, I am back to the basic bash. I thought of migrating my setup to the server but that seems impractical since I am working on at least 3 servers on daily basis + id have to do the same thing on other servers I might work on and every server that I work on in the future. A simple solution would be to upload my conf and dot files to GH and clone them in my user directory BUT my configuration is very specific to my arch setup and so it would be a pain to create a separate branch which is compatible with ubuntu, fedora, popos, gentoo etc etc etc. Doing it once takes a few hours, maintaining it takes many hours which I do not want to spend.

Any solution?

Comment: When you `ssh`, your local terminal (terminal emulator) is the same. You probably mean the configuration of your *shell*. Relevant: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, I did mean shell.

Answer (score 0):

> Any solution?

No, You have to transfer (and port) the configuration files.

In the end, you are running a different software (shell) on another server and your ssh client is just showing you characters without understanding what they mean. It might not even be `bash` on the server.
Anything arch specific would need to be translated for other machine you are connecting to since that is the machine that must perform the commands all the bytes for the characters (and colors) you see.

You have some *very limited* amount of influence via only environment variables, for which the standard SSH server accepts a select few values, typically only those affecting your locale, though you can extend this be changing the server sshd configuration `AcceptEnv ...` parameter, and configure the client side to include `SendEnv ...`.
But, you can't know if the `PAGER` you select, or a fancy `PS1` prompt would even function on another machine.